# Theme value is not getting applied as a CSS class in the root component of the application. I am using spartacus 5.2

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Theme value is not getting applied as a CSS class in the root component of the application. I am using spartacus 5.2. In backoffice we have theme "electronics". As per me it should be added automatically if theme is set. Am I missing something?

[image]